# Ruby on Rails: Has and belongs to many relationship: how do I destroy a relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a lot harder in code, than in real life. =)
But anyway,
My Users have managers, and vice versa...

How do I remove the relationship?

```
@selected_user = User.find(params[:id])
@selected_user.managers.delete_if{|x| x.standard_user_id == params[:id].to_i}
```

This is a self referential has and belongs to many relationship, so I have another table that has only two columns of foreign keys, both pointing to the Users table.  This lookup table does not have a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @report = User.find(params[:report])
    @manager = User.find(params[:manager])
    @manager.standard_users.delete(@report)
```

Managers have standard users
standard users have managers

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt this work ? `@selected_user.managers.each{|x| x.destroy!}` or `Managers.delete_all "standard_user_id = params[:id]"`

Comment: I should probably have added that it is a self referential has and belongs to many relationship

Comment: thing is, there isn't actually a column called managers or standard_users in the users table.

Comment: as it turns out, and i feel lame for having this issue, I was calling the wrong method. self referential thing can get confusing if variable names don't work right